# 18.04 slow boot, stopped on "Started login service"

Tags: boot, server, desktop-environments, 18.04

I have fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new machine and I have compared its boot time to an old machine running 16.04.  The time between the grub menu selection and the login prompt is significantly longer in the new 18.04, which is strange taking into account that the new machine performance is significantly higher than the old one.

In order to support RAID, I had to install Ubuntu server and the `ubuntu-desktop` package on top of it, I don't know if this can be related to the issue.

Apparently it waits for a few seconds after displaying the last message on the text console "Started login service".

These are some reports:

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 17.552s (firmware) + 2.418s (loader) + 2.571s (kernel) + 21.544s (userspace) = 44.086s
graphical.target reached after 14.278s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 10
         13.254s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.622s apt-daily.service
          1.660s apt-daily-upgrade.service
           720ms fwupd.service
           316ms systemd-logind.service
           277ms dev-md0.device
           213ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           186ms NetworkManager.service
           178ms systemd-resolved.service
           100ms systemd-journal-flush.service
```

Any ideas about what could be causing this delay and how to speed it up?